# Python - with pip install I recieve ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gevent

I want to install gevent with pip but when I try it I'll get in the end this:

```
    ...
   File "c:\users\draffix\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Draffix\gevent\setup.py", line 237, in build_extension

    result = build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 517, in build_extension

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: ['path']

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python33\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\draffix\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_
Draffix\\gevent\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'ex
ec'))" install --record c:\users\draffix\appdata\local\temp\pip-gt7qw6-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\draffix\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Draffix\gevent
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Draffix\pip\pip.log
```

I'm using windows 7, python 3.3., Microsoft Visual 2010. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you the specific reason for the `ValueError`, but I'm sure your bigger concern is getting gevent installed. At this time, however, it does not support Python 3. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/issues/38) for updates.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Anyway I downgraded python to 2.7. and now everything going well.